# Find XPATH with namespace based on attribute element

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I have the following xml:

```
<assets>
    <asset type="full">
        <file_name>WME__HD_2CH_EN_16X9_178_2398_FINAL.mov</file_name>
    </asset>
    ...
</assets>
```

I have multiple `asset` blocks, so I need to reference the attribute `type = "full"`. This is what I currently have to reference them all --

```
node.xpath("//t:assets/t:asset/t:file_name/text()", 
            namespaces={'t':'http://apple.com/itunes/importer'})
```

How would I reference **only** the asset with `type = "full"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `[@type="full"]` attribute selector onto `t:asset`:

```
node.xpath("//t:assets/t:asset[@type='full']/t:file_name/text()", 
        namespaces={'t':'http://apple.com/itunes/importer'})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
node.xpath("//t:assets/t:asset[@type='full']/t:file_name/text()", 
        namespaces={'t':'http://apple.com/itunes/importer'})
```

`@` notation is used to select attributes through xpath.

So, `t:asset[@type='full']` means select all `asset` element that have attribute `type` and value `full`.

Take a look here [xpath synatx](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp).

Answer (score 0):

```
node.xpath("//t:assets/t:asset[@type='full']/t:file_name/text()", 
        namespaces={'t':'http://apple.com/itunes/importer'})
```